# Android jetpack compose canvas : How to adjust brightness,contrast, saturation function drawImage?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-canvas

Is there any way to adjust the image's **brightness**, **contrast**, **saturation** , **warmth**,... when using drawImage in canvas. i tried everything but can only adjust saturation or brightness and contrast at the same time. i found some way like postconcat matrix but ColorMatrix in compose doesn't have postconcat method :(

```
                drawImage(
                    imageBitmaps[currentBitmapIndex].image,
                    dstOffset = IntOffset.Zero,
                    dstSize = IntSize(viewWidth, viewHeight),
                    colorFilter = ColorFilter.colorMatrix(ColorMatrix(
                        // Brightness and contrast
                        floatArrayOf(
                            contrast, 0f, 0f, 0f, brightness,
                            0f, contrast, 0f, 0f, brightness,
                            0f, 0f, contrast, 0f, brightness,
                            0f, 0f, 0f, 1f, 0f
                        )
                    ).apply {
                        // saturation
                        setToSaturation(saturation)
                        // just one of them work. if i remove setToSaturation brightness and contrast work fine
                        // or saturation override and brightness and contrast 
                    })
                )
///
```

Answer (score 0):

`android.graphics.ColorMatrix` has `postConcat` function, but `androidx.compose.ui.graphics.ColorMatrix` has `timesAssign` instead of it.

In order to achieve what you want, you can do it like this:

```
drawImage(
    imageBitmaps[currentBitmapIndex].image,
    dstOffset = IntOffset.Zero,
    dstSize = IntSize(viewWidth, viewHeight),
    colorFilter = ColorFilter.colorMatrix(ColorMatrix(
        // Brightness and contrast
        floatArrayOf(
            contrast, 0f, 0f, 0f, brightness,
            0f, contrast, 0f, 0f, brightness,
            0f, 0f, contrast, 0f, brightness,
            0f, 0f, 0f, 1f, 0f
        )
    ).apply {
        // saturation
        val saturationMatrix = ColorMatrix()
        saturationMatrix.setToSaturation(saturation)
        timesAssign(saturationMatrix)
    })
```

Check it here: [Android Developers resource](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/graphics/ColorMatrix#timesAssign(androidx.compose.ui.graphics.ColorMatrix))